# Eigenvalues of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If A  is  a singular square matrix , what are the eigenvalue  of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ ?

My attempt:

I know that  if    $\mathrm{rank}(A) < n- 1$ then   $\mathrm{adj}(A) = 0$. I think that the eigenvalue  of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ will  $0$.

Is  its correct ?

Any hints/solution will be aappreciated ..

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is $n-1$, then its adjugate has rank one.

Comment: okks,@LordSharktheUnknown..let me thinks more

Comment: Please not that before accepting my answer that it is just an observation and as @Chappers remarked there is more to the $n-1$-case. As his answer is more thorough, I encourage you to accept it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this blog post](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/eigenvalues-of-adjugate-matrix/) points out, we have $\operatorname{adj}{(U^{-1}AU)} = U^{-1}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) U$ for any invertible $U$. Since any matrix $A$ can be reduced to a triangular one $B$ by such a transformation, $B=U^{-1}AU$, we have
$$ \operatorname{adj}(B) = U^{-1}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) U. $$
The diagonal elements of $B$ are $\lambda_i$, the eigenvalues of $A$, and a calculation shows that the adjugate of an upper triangular matrix is also upper triangular, and the diagonal elements are $\prod_{j \neq i} \lambda_j$.

So the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ are the same as those of $\operatorname{adj}(B)$, which are the diagonal elements, i.e. $\prod_{j \neq i} \lambda_j$. Of course, this means that if $\dim\ker{A}>1$, $\operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$, while if $\dim\ker{A} = 1$, $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ has exactly one nonzero eigenvalue, the product of the others.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just a collection of direct properties:

If $\mathrm{rank}(A)<n-1$, then the only eigenvalue of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is $0$ as $\mathrm{adj}(A)=\mathbf0$.

---

If on the other hand $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n-1$, then $0$ is again an eigenvalue of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ as $\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{adj}(A))=1$, i.e. $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{adj}(A)))=n-1$ by the rank-nullity theorem. Note, that $0$ thus has geometric multiplicity $n-1$ instead of $n$ as before.

Note that this does not mean that there is not more to the $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n-1$-case.